# Calling my own event code and custom event code in c#

Tags: c#, events, controls

I have made a WinForms application with a custom richtextbox control.

I am referring it as a Windows control (a dll file) in my project. In my program for the richtextbox I have written functionality inside it's textchanged event.

I want to do additional work only after the textchanged event is fired or in other ways once the text is added to the textbox. Something like I want to call a function foo() in the text_changedevent. It only calls foo and fails to process the underlying textchanged event.

Any way in C# I can make it process the internal textchanged event first, and then look into my text changed event?

think of the scenario I have written the code for mytextbox_textchanged

```
private void txt_code_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //some code which will always be called whenever textchanged event occurs.
    }
```

Now I inherit this control in my project say MyApp1. Here I have a label where I want to display the number of lines contained inside my textbox. So I would write

```
private void my_inherited_txt_code_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //code to update the label with my_inherited_txt_code.lines.length
    }
```

so my problem was, I first wanted the txt_code_TextChanged event to be called and then do the code written inside my_inherited_txt_code_TextChanged. Which was solved by writing

```
private void my_inherited_txt_code_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnTextChanged(e);
        MessageBox.Show("foo");
    }
```

Comment: could you post some code to demonstrate the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean:

```
protected override void OnTextChanged(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnTextChanged(e);
    // your code here...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I cant see why you shouldnt be able to call a method from the text_changed event?
Do you get any errors or what happens exactly?